# active link for most recent post on vertical tabs

Tags: wp-query, theme-development, loop, css

I'm trying to add the css class `.is-active` to my vertical tab links inside my loop.

By default, the page loads the most recent post first. How can I make most recent tab/post active with `.is-active`?

```
<?php
    $races_2016='0';
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'races',
    'order'     => 'DESC',
    'parent'    => '$races_2016',
    'orderby'   => 'date',

);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<!-- Tab Buttons -->
    <div class="vertical-tabs">
    <p><?php echo date('Y'); ?> Race Results</p>
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="js-vertical-tab vertical-tab page-item" rel="<?php the_ID();?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>

        <?php endwhile; else: ?>    
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    </div>
    <!-- Tab Buttons -->
```

Comment: What defines if a post gets the `is-active` class? You just want it on your first post?

Comment: Would like the most recent post in the tab to apply the class ".is-active" I'm using "orderby => date and tabs rel="the_ID();"

Comment: The current answer is correct. You would use `$the_quer->current_post` like so: `class="<?php echo ( 0 == $the_query->current_post ) ? 'active ' : ''; ?>js-vertical-tab vertical-tab page-item"`

Comment: This works! ty all

Comment: please click the checkmark on the answer so future readers know that this solved your issue! Glad it helped.

Comment: Howdy_McGee how would I make this active link turn off after user clicks to another tab item , it seems to stay on ?

Comment: JavaScript. That's a question better suited for [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). [JQuery Onclick Handler](http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/03/working-with-events-part-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties) provides **current_post** property inside the loop which starts from 0. So if you want to target first post in the loop you should just check if **$the_query->current_post** equals 0:

```
if ( $the_query->current_post == 0 ) {
 echo 'is_active';
}
```

Comment: Like mentioned above this works perfect! thank you! please check as "answered"